# How to make ffmpeg executable everywhere?

Tags: ffmpeg, executable

I have installed `ffmpeg` by following [this tutorial on trac.ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

Now, `ffmpeg` works if I `cd` to `bin` and execute it with `./ffmpeg`

I wonder if I could execute `ffmpeg` just by typing `ffmpeg` in a terminal from anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add ffmpeg directory to your $PATH.
Assuming you're using bash open ~/.bashrc file and add at the bottom:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<path where you installed ffmpeg>
```

and reload bash ( close and open terminal again or type 'bash' ).

edit:
PATH represents list of directories that your shell is using to find binary files. So you need to add directory, not the file, path to that variable.
Assuming that you executed everything exactly the way that manual said you need to add to you .bashrc that command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Comment: Like this? export PATH=$PATH:/bin/ffmpeg

Comment: I think my app installed to /root/bin. What if i move that apps to $HOME or /bin?

Comment: Okay, i have copied all ffmpeg applications to /bin directory and when i type ffmpeg, it works now :) Thank you for the path env.

Comment: The guide installs to `~/bin`, and this directory is already in the `$PATH`, so no need to edit the `$PATH`.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 9):

## You don't need to edit your `PATH` or `~/.bashrc`

- The guide "installs" `ffmpeg` inside `~/bin` so it does not potentially interfere with conflicting repository packages.
- **There is no need to edit your `PATH` or `~/.bashrc` as shown in the accepted answer**. `~/bin` is already in the `PATH` by default (take a look at `~/.profile`), but `~/bin` is not included when you login if it does not exist (and it did not exist before you compiled), but you can easily "refresh" it as shown below.

## All you need to do is this:

```
hash -r
. ~/.profile
```

**Alternatively you can simply log out then log in.**

Now you can run `ffmpeg` from any directory and it will automatically execute the `ffmpeg` binary in `~/bin` (for the particular user who compiled `ffmpeg`). [All of this is explained in the guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#Usage) you linked to.

## Getting it to work for all users

The above instructions are for the single user who compiled `ffmpeg`. If you have multiple users you can just move or copy the compiled `ffmpeg` binary into `/usr/local/bin`.