# Symlink the ffmpeg command to avconv

Tags: 14.04, ffmpeg, avconv

I’m on Ubuntu 14.04 which has no ffmpeg. Instead, it uses avconv. However, an application I want to use relies on ffmpeg. So I tried the following:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/avconv /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

to create a symbolic link from the (not present) ffmpeg binary to the avconc binary. However, when I type the ffmpeg command to my terminal, it still says: 'Command not found.'

Is there a way to symlink the ffmpeg command to avconv a bit like I did it with the binaries?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04's avconv automatically adds that symlink, you shouldn't have to manually create it. Please add output of `type -a ffmpeg` and `ldd $(which ffmpeg)` to your post

Comment: @muru The so-called "`ffmpeg`" from libav-tools is not from FFmpeg and is missing many features. Also, IIRC, the fake "`ffmpeg`" was removed by 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Symlinking is usually a messy way to do this, and `avconv` is a very poor "replacement" for `ffmpeg`. You have some other options though:

- [Use the Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media), or
- [Download a static `ffmpeg` binary](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and put it somewhere in your `PATH`*, such as `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` ([you may have to run `hash -r && source ~/.profile` after moving it to `~/bin`](https://askubuntu.com/a/614952/59378) if you prefer that location).

Some additional, but probably less helpful options:

- [Compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).
- Or upgrade Ubuntu. Recent versions provide `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg.

<sub>* I'm assuming your application is looking for `ffmpeg` via your user's `PATH` and not pointing to an absolute, hardcoded, specific directory.</sub>